# how to design uicollectionviewcell's pushing depends on cell type?

Tags: push, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, springboard

Good day! i have uicollectionview, in cells are showing different documents... is it possible to design pushing cell and show different view controllers depends on cell(document) type?

Comment: what do you mean by "design pushing cell"?

Comment: thanks for answering=) it means not to use code where i should analyze what  type of cell user picked and then choose nib for this cell but design it on springboard=)

Comment: Can you please add more description to your question? by design it on springboard you mean interface builder/storyboard?

Comment: yes) i mean to design all storyboard segue for nibs in IB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `UICollectionViewCell` is aware of which document it is supposed to show, you can use that information to discriminate between documents once you leave the view. Control-drag from your cell to the new view controller in Interface Builder and implement the distinction in `prepareForSegue`

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetailController"]) {
        MyDetailViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)sender;
        // depending on your cell implementation, e.g. with an enum
        destination.documentType = cell.documentType;
   }
}
```

Comment: So to designing different pushing is not possible in storyboard... Mundi's true code allows to control filling of view controller. That is pattern factory =)

Comment: It is possible. But the above is preferable.